# Using a textarea to modify a MySQL table field

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, textarea

Basically I want a user to be able to create a list that looks something like this:

```
Please give me all books by:

James Arnold
Tom Seaver
```

I only need line breaks preserved...

My code is giving me a problem: When I save the information into the database, the formatting is being preserved, but when I put the information into the textarea, there are a lot of extra spaces. I have attached a picture so you can see what it looks like.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
        header('Location: ../index.php');

    require ("../login.php");

    include ("header.php");
    include ("subnav.php");

    $user_id = $_SESSION['user'];
    $form_show = true;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['notes'])) {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE user=:id");
            $stmt->bindValue(':id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $num_rows = count($rows);
            if ($num_rows == 0) {
                $form_show = false;
                $errors[] = 'You do not currently have any notes to edit, therefore nothing to delete!.';
            }
            else {
                $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM notes WHERE user=:id");
                $stmt->bindValue(':id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();
                $errors[] = 'Your notes have been successfully deleted.';
                $form_show = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE user=:id");
            $stmt->bindValue(':id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $num_rows = count($rows);
            if ($num_rows == 0) {
                $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO notes (user, notes) VALUES (:user, :notes)");
                $stmt->bindValue(':user', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->bindValue(':notes', trim($_POST['notes']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();
                echo 'Your notes have been successfully added!';
                $form_show = false;
            }
            else {
                $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE notes SET notes=:notes WHERE user=:id");
                $stmt->bindValue(':notes',trim($_POST['notes']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindValue(':id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();
                echo 'Your notes have been successfully updated!';
                $form_show = false;
            }
        }
    }

?>

    <?php
        if (!empty($errors))
            foreach($errors as $error)
                echo $error;
    ?>

    <?php
        if ($form_show == true) { ?>
            <p>Use this page to add any notes you would like to list for your subscription. For example, if you want all books by a particular artist, here is the place to add that information!</p>

            <form action="" method="post">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Notes: <br>
                            <textarea name="notes" rows="30" cols="70">

                            <?php
                            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE user=:id");
                            $stmt->bindValue(':id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
                            $num_rows = count($rows);
                            if ($num_rows != 0)
                                foreach ($rows as $row)
                                    echo $row['notes'];
                            ?>

                            </textarea>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="submit" value="Modify Notes" name ="submit" id="submit">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </form>
<?php   } ?>



<?php   
    include ("footer.php");
?>
```

Here is a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't the following query:

```
"UPDATE notes SET notes=:notes WHERE id=:id"
```

be:

```
"UPDATE notes SET notes=:notes WHERE user=:id"
```

For the second one, you can try replacing `nl2br($_POST['notes'])` with

```
nl2br( trim($_POST['notes']) )
```

I still don't understand what the second question is?

---

The second problem is generated because of the available empty spaces inside your text-area. The following looks ugly, but will provide you with what you desire.

```
<textarea name="notes" rows="30" cols="70"><?php $stmt=$ db->prepare("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE user=:id"); $stmt->bindValue(':id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT); $stmt->execute(); $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); $num_rows = count($rows); if ($num_rows != 0) foreach ($rows as $row) echo $row['notes']; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Yes, I had the UPDATE statement wrong, thank you. That solved the update problem. As for the second question, when I add a note and the text displays, there are all kinds of spaces on both sides of the text that aren't there when I originally create the note.

Comment: I have added the changes to the code. There is only one problem, and that is the extra white space in the notes, in the front of the notes. The picture in my original post will show this.

Comment: @JimRomeFan : What is reason to populate the record with `<ul><li>`?

Comment: @JimRomeFan : For that, you can remove the line between `<textarea>` and `<?php ?>` code. And try it now..

Comment: You know what? I just read about the textarea ending tag having to be on all one line, and it did work perfectly. I can't think of any other tag that has to work that way. Thanks for your dilligence. The ul li was just formatting that I use for all my forms for display purposes with my current project.